# Comparing With Dictionary Values(?)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently working on a self project, a simple ATM. I'm using a dictionary which has a set name, pin, and amount of money for savings and checking accounts. When I try to compare values from a dictionary and a user input, for some reason it doesn't work.

```py
bank = [
    {'UserName': 'Bob', 'PIN': '0001', 'CheckingBalance': '1234', 'SavingsBalance': '12345'},
    {'UserName': 'Steve', 'PIN': '0002', 'CheckingBalance': '12', 'SavingsBalance': '123'},]

def withdraw():
    while "w":
        for record in bank:
            # checks for checking or savings account & amount to withdraw
            account = input("CHECKING (C) OR SAVINGS (S): ").lower
            amount = int(input("AMOUNT FOR WITHDRAWAL: "))
            # checks for enough balance and negatives for checking account
            if account == "c":
                if amount > record['CheckingBalance']:
                    amount = input("INVALID. PLEASE CHOOSE A DIFFERENT AMOUNT: ")
                elif amount <= 0:
                    amount = input("INVALID. PLEASE CHOOSE A DIFFERENT AMOUNT: ")
                else:
                    print("WITHDRAWAL SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED.")
                    break

#this is part of the withdraw method and for some reason when I'm comparing the amount and record['CheckingBalance'] or record['SavingsBalance'], it doesn't work. 

def deposit():
    while "d":
        # checks for checking or savings account & amount to deposit
        account = input("CHECKING (C) OR SAVINGS (S): ").lower
        amount = int(input("AMOUNT TO DEPOSIT: "))
        # checks for 0 and negatives for checking account
        if account == "c":
            if amount <= 0:
                print(input("INVALID. PLEASE CHOOSE A DIFFERENT AMOUNT: "))
            else:
                print("DEPOSIT SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED")
            break
        # checks for 0 and negatives for savings account
        if account == "s":
            if amount <= 0:
                print(input("INVALID. PLEASE CHOOSE A DIFFERENT AMOUNT: "))
            else:
                print("DEPOSIT SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED")
                break

#this is the deposit method

#both of these methods, I'm having a bug where after I input an amount, it prompts me to "CHECKINGS (C) OR SAVINGS(S) for some reason.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionaries contain strings instead of ints. Try changing

```
bank = [
    {'UserName': 'Bob', 'PIN': '0001', 'CheckingBalance': '1234', 'SavingsBalance': '12345'},
    {'UserName': 'Steve', 'PIN': '0002', 'CheckingBalance': '12', 'SavingsBalance': '123'},]
```

to

```
bank = [
    {'UserName': 'Bob', 'PIN': '0001', 'CheckingBalance': 1234, 'SavingsBalance': 12345},
    {'UserName': 'Steve', 'PIN': '0002', 'CheckingBalance': 12, 'SavingsBalance': 123},]
```

In addition, with `while "w":` and `while "d":` you have created `while True` loops (endless loops) and I don't see any breaks of these loops.